# React - Catch event in sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My parent component looks like

```js
<Tabs tabs={[
            {
              id: "Comp1",
              content: (
                <Comp1/>
              ),
            },
            {
              id: "Comp2",
              content: (
                <Comp2/>
              ),
            },
          ]}
        />
```

The requirement is to execute a function in comp1 on a button click in comp2 ?

What is the best way to handle such situations?

I am not much inclined towards handling it through redux-store, and have doubts over passing it through props

Comment: lift state up the the common ancestor component. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Props would be the best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example, in this scenario, `Child` will execute some function (which focuses an input) from `FancyInput` component, when clicking the `div`.

```
function FancyInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focusInput: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    },
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} />;
}
FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);

let Child = (props) => {
  return <div onClick={props.callback}>Hello</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  let inputRef = useRef();
  let callback = () => inputRef.current.focusInput();
  return (
    <div>
      <FancyInput ref={inputRef} />
      <Child callback={callback} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: +1 this is exactly what I need but it also highlights my problem with react. How did you learn this approach? I mean I see the functions documented, but knowing to use them this way takes a leap.

Comment: @RyanHamilton Well if you know how to use `useImperativeHandle` it means you know you can invoke some methods of child (`FancyInput`) from Parent (`App`) method right? Then you might also know that you can also invoke some parent method (`callback` in this case) from child (`Child`) if you pass that method as props from parent. Using these facts I think you can deduce that you can invoke `FancyInput`s method from `Child`.

Comment: I thought maybe you had found a good book/guide/course you could recommend. I have read the react docs and completed an online course by moshe but never connected the dots like you did. Well done and I used your example to create similar mechanism in my code. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanHamilton The new official docs are pretty good (react.dev)

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to uplift and define the function of `comp1` inside the parent component and then pass it to both the children `comp1` and `comp2`.

This way `comp2` and `comp1` both can access the function.